# How to get GCM ID using phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, push

I am trying to get GCM ID with the latest version of [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

I have built many sample code from the internet but none of them are working.

I have followed the steps from [phonegaptut.com](http://phonegaptut.com/2016/05/31/how-to-send-push-notifications-in-phonegap-application/), and [phonegappro.com](http://phonegappro.com/phonegap-tutorial/apache-cordova-phonegap-push-notification-tutorial-part-1/), and this [phonegap-plugin-push example](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/EXAMPLES.md) too.

I have followed the instructions carefully but the GCM ID is not there.

These are the steps I have taken:

- I create new project on GCM and get the project number
- cordova create GCM com.phonegaptut.gcm GCM
- cd GCM
- cordova platform add android
- cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="MY SENDER ID"
- Edit Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PhonegapTut</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style> textarea { width:100%; } </style>    
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

        function onDeviceReady(){    
            console.log("Device Ready");    
            var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "MY SENDER ID"},"ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } );

            push.on('registration', function(data) {    
                console.log(data.registrationId);    
                $("#gcm_id").val(data.registrationId);
            });    

            push.on('notification', function(data) {    
                console.log(data.message);    
                alert(data.title+" Message: " +data.message);    
                // data.title,    
                // data.count,    
                // data.sound,    
                // data.image,    
                // data.additionalData    
            });   

            push.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log(e.message);    
            });    
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Push Notification Example</h2>
    Your GCM ID : <br/>
    <textarea id="gcm_id" rows="10"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

- Cordova build android
- Cordova run android –device

However, the GCM ID does not appear; can anyone see anything wrong with the code?

Comment: is there any other error you are getting in console ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO.  I have tidied your capitalization and links to external resources plus improved your grammar and code layout to make your question easier to understand in the hope that it will help you receive the help you are seeking and improve this question's benefit to people who may have the same problem in the future.  If you feel you can improve your question further please click on `edit` just below the android `cordova` `plugins` `push` tags.

Comment: @lukkea thank you for your correction, arpit-vasani no error in console the application stuck on registering id

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution

- phonegap create my-app --template phonegap-template-push
- phonegap platform add android
- edit and replace SENDER_ID "XXXXXXX" with your GCM project number in config.xml

> Blockquote

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.6.0">
<param name="SENDER_ID" value="XXXXXXX" />
</plugin>
```

- edit and replace SENDER_ID "XXXXXXX" with your GCM project number in js/index.js file

> Blockquote

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
android: {
senderID: "XXXXXXX"
},
browser: {
pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
},
ios: {
alert: "true",
badge: "true",
sound: "true"
},
windows: {}
});'
```

- add a new code to set registration id

  console.log('registration event: ' + data.registrationId);
  **document.getElementById("gcm_id").innerHTML = data.registrationId;**
- add < div > in your index.html to display GCM ID

> Blockquote

```
<div id="gcm_id"> registration id: </div>
```

- phonegap build android
- phonegap run android --device

and your GCM ID will be displayed inside the DIV